# How to add space before bullet points in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to add space before bullet points . My requirement like

This is paragraph1

- The text line one

- The text line two

This is paragraph 2

- The text line one

- The text line two

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: give `padding-left` to `ul` .

Comment: [**`JSFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/93eug/1/) setting the `ul` a `margin-left`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *is* spacing before bullet points by default. If there isn’t, you are probably using a “Reset CSS” of some kind.

To set the spacing to a desired value, set `padding-left` and `margin-left` of both `ul` and `li` elements to zero and then set one of them to the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting margin to `li`

```
li{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f98VM/5/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
li {
  margin-left:1em;
}
```

Comment: It should be `li { padding-left: 1em; }`, as margin pushes everything to the right. Here: [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/mugayari/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `CSS` to `li` as per your requirement.

**HTML Code**

```
<p>This is my paragraph1</p>
<ul><li> List One </li>
    <li> List Two </li>
    <li> List Three </li>
</ul>
<p>This is my paragraph 2</p>
<ul><li> List One </li>
    <li> List Two </li>
    <li> List Three </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
  margin-left:1em;
}
```

**[JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/Gagan_Gami/JmJAH/)**

Answer (score 0):

apply margin-left to ul

**Working Fiddle example is here:**

```
Code:

    [http://jsfiddle.net/Sharan_thethy/MNaUn/][1]
```

I hope this will help you